# Behat "base_url" from command line

Tags: behat, mink

I would like to know if it's possible to set the base_url via the command line. Example

```
bin/behat --base_url=http://google.fr
```

I would like to avoid creating a new profile and passing it via the command line each time I have to test a new url, for flexibility purpose.

Is there any trick here to do this ?

Thank you.

Comment: It is a bit puzzling why you don't mind passing the base_url on the command line, but passing the profile (which is less characters) is not ok. :)

Comment: aderuwe, I had the same question as original poster because we spin up  new servers at will for testing branches. The URL is different for each instance. Storing these urls in behat.yml is not ideal.

Comment: Totally forgot to validate the answer. @bitlather you can use my solution

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the solution by myself.

Just pass the base_url in the BEHAT_PARAM environment variable.

```
export BEHAT_PARAMS="context[parameters][base_url]=http://google.fr"
```

Then run behat

```
bin/behat
```

Comment: Does not work at least with Behat 3.2 and ends up in `ConfigurationLoadingException: Environment variable `BEHAT_PARAMS` should contain a valid JSON`

Solution is to use:

`export BEHAT_PARAMS='{"extensions" : {"Behat\\MinkExtension" : {"base_url" : "http://google.fr/"}}}'` see: http://behat.org/en/latest/user_guide/configuration.html#environment-variable-behat-params

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively if you are using Mink you could define a profile in behat.yml

```
# behat.yml
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            base_url: http://local.mysite.com
            goutte: ~
            selenium2: ~

dev:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            base_url: http://dev.mysite.com
```

And then you can run your tests against local.mysite.com by default with

```
$ behat
```

Or against dev.mysite.com with

```
$ behat --profile=dev
```

Answer (score 5):

In Behat 3, this parameter seems to have become JSON, so it works like:

```
export BEHAT_PARAMS='{"extensions":{"Behat\\MinkExtension":{"base_url":"https://google.com/"}}}'
```

**Important** these params are not *overrides*, they are defaults, and get *over-written* by behat.yml.
So you must UNSET the base_url in behat.yml for this CLI setting to work.

```
extensions:
  Behat\MinkExtension:
    # YOU MUST EDIT THIS YOURSELF!
    # Either set this here, or set the base_url via BEHAT_PARAMS
    # base_url: 'https://my.livesite.com/'
```

(Refs: [feature-request](https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/575), [clue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/behat/tYS8hqxWWNg/o-H9-f3f9mcJ))

Answer (score 4):

The shorter way of achieving the same as per [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19832800/458356) would be just to pass the environment variables before the command itself:

```
BEHAT_PARAMS="context[parameters][base_url]=http://google.fr" bin/behat
```