# How to get parameters from CMD for Behat?

Tags: bdd, behat, mink

I am testing new features in the new project branch, which has a new URL. I need to dynamically change the base url for Behat tests. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The right way of doing that would be to change the `base_url` in your behat.yml configuration. It's a new branch, it has new features, there's no reason why you can't or shouldn't change the test configuration for it. When you merge it with the master, you simply leave the config out of merge or change the `base_url` back.

If you want to do it via the command line still, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19815144/458356) for details. This might not override the original value if you do have a config though, I've never tested this.

```
BEHAT_PARAMS="context[parameters][base_url]=http://google.fr" bin/behat
```